# Reindexing list of f(x) to extract matrix f(x-y)

Tags: python, numpy

I am not sure how articulate/name this problem, so I apologise in advance if this has already been asked/answered. Or if anyone has a better suggestion for a title then let me know...

I want to evaluate a function `f(x)` but I want to do this over a difference of values, i.e. `f(x-y)`, 2D outputting a matrix of values.
Now the easiest way to do this is:

```
dat_array = [[f(x-y) for x in xvalues] for y in xvalues]
```

where `xvalues` is a list of numbers.
The function `f` in question is quite computationally expensive to calculate, and I need to calculate it for many points.

However, it seems that calculating the array in this way is rather inefficient as there is a high degree of symmetry in the problem. For example I can get all possible values for the differences using the (clunky) code:

```
diff_vals = np.unique(np.sort(np.append(xlist , 2*xlist)))
```

My question is then: is it possible to simply evaluate `f` over the list `diff_vals`, and then extract `dat_array` by reindexing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is stuff in the `functools` module to cache the results of function calls. So you could use that with your expensive function and not worry about producing `diff_vals`. Have a look at the `lru_cache` decorator:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def computationally_expensive_function(x):
    # do something computationally expensive
```

The cache will remember the parameters used when calling this function and return the result without the calculation having to be performed again.

Comment: Doesn't answer the literal question but it's conceptually much cleaner. +1

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your `diff_vals` is supposed to work... but yes, computer all possible differences, make the list unique using `set`, calculate the expensive operation's value for the set, then put them into a 2D array:

```
diffs = set(x - y for x in xvalues for y in yvalues)
values = { diff: f(diff) for diff in diffs }
[[values[x - y] for x in xvalues] for y in yvalues]
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.unique` has a `return_inverse` keyword that can be used here:

```
>>> a = np.r_[0:3, 6:9]
>>> D = np.subtract.outer(a, a)
>>> D                                                                                                               
array([[ 0, -1, -2, -6, -7, -8],                                                                                    
       [ 1,  0, -1, -5, -6, -7],                                                                                    
       [ 2,  1,  0, -4, -5, -6],                                                                                    
       [ 6,  5,  4,  0, -1, -2],                                                                                    
       [ 7,  6,  5,  1,  0, -1],                                                                                    
       [ 8,  7,  6,  2,  1,  0]])                                                                                   
>>> unq, bck = np.unique(D, return_inverse=True)
>>> unq                                                                                                             
array([-8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8])                                                 
>>> bck                                                                                                             
array([ 7,  6,  5,  2,  1,  0,  8,  7,  6,  3,  2,  1,  9,  8,  7,  4,  3,                                          
        2, 12, 11, 10,  7,  6,  5, 13, 12, 11,  8,  7,  6, 14, 13, 12,  9,                                          
        8,  7])                                                                                                     
>>> f_unq = 10 * unq
>>> f_D = f_unq[bck].reshape(6, 6)
>>> f_D                                                                                                             
array([[  0, -10, -20, -60, -70, -80],                                                                              
       [ 10,   0, -10, -50, -60, -70],                                                                              
       [ 20,  10,   0, -40, -50, -60],                                                                              
       [ 60,  50,  40,   0, -10, -20],                                                                              
       [ 70,  60,  50,  10,   0, -10],                                                                              
       [ 80,  70,  60,  20,  10,   0]])
```